# Confusion about RelayBandwidthRate

Tags: relays, middle

when i set a RelayBandwidthRate e.g. 600 KB/s does it mean i have 600 KB/s bidirectional (e.g. 300 KB/s download and 300 KB/s upload) or does i mean i have 600 KB/s in both directions, 1200 KB/s in total ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RelayBandwidthRate` - like **all** rate directives in `torrc` is same-in-both-ways, i.e. 600 means 600in+600out. If you're throttling your bandwidth - if you need to maintain a constant 24/7 operations in a free/hosting-included traffic limits, it's **not enough** to specify just this setting, drop a line if you need full details. It works *a bit different as it should be* in real world.

UPDATE: So - here it how it goes to **actually** work as it *should* from the docs:

- `BandwidthRate XKBytes` and `BandwidthBurst XKBytes` will actually limit the speed in *most* of cases. To limit it strictly use 75% of `BandwidthBurst` limit in `BandwidthRate`
- `AccountingMax DailyLimitKBytes` and `AccountingStart day` will ensure the daily limit to be kept. Without it there can be some overruns - not big ones, but there are some.
- `AccountingRule in|out|sum` - use it according to your hosting plan
- remember that DNS queries are **not** taken into this accounting, so use as a limit 80-85% volume of traffic.

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated. I've got a 1,9 TB monthly cap and the terms suggest I should limit my rate to 5 Mbit/s. Are the following settings suffcient ? `RelayBandwidthRate 320 KBytes`, `AccountingMax 1800 MB`, AccountingStart month 5 00:00,  `AccountingRule sum`. Thanks for your time!